# Querying all constraints with a particular foreign key option

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have several tables with foreign key in MySql. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE rooms (
  room_no int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  room_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  building_no int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (room_no),
  KEY building_no (building_no),
CONSTRAINT rooms_ibfk_1 
  FOREIGN KEY (building_no) 
  REFERENCES buildings (building_no) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I would like to query every table within a schema that has a foriegn key constraint and know the additional options. 
I've tried the following queries :

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE;

select *
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
where CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY';
```

Unfortunately, they don't give me the on delete or on update action.

Comment: Would `SHOW CREATE TABLE` be sufficent, or is it a requirement that you be able to dynamically query by table name?

Answer (score 0):

If your tables are INNODB (which I assume they are given the foreign keys), check out [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`SYS_FOREIGN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-sys-foreign-table.html).  From the documentation, the `type` field gives you the `ON DELETE` / `ON UPDATE` action:

> A collection of bit flags with information about the foreign key column, ORed together. 1 = ON DELETE CASCADE, 2 = ON UPDATE SET NULL, 4 = ON UPDATE CASCADE, 8 = ON UPDATE SET NULL, 16 = ON DELETE NO ACTION, 32 = ON UPDATE NO ACTION.

You can query by `FOR_NAME` or `REF_NAME`.